# How to create a graph like StackOverflow reputation graph using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, charts

I'm new to d3.js. Although I find it very cool, its samples are more complex than I need!
I just want to have a simple chart to show the sales volume in previous 10 months.

A 2 dimension chart, horizontal axis contains months and the vertical shows the volumes.

**Question:** Is there any easier way to work with d3.js, maybe a library or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [nvd3.js](http://nvd3.org/), they added a layer on top of d3.js that makes really simple to build charts.

Here is an example for what you want:

```js
var data = [{
  "key": "Sales",
  "values": [
    { x:1, y: 132 }, 
    { x:2, y: 121 }, 
    { x:3, y: 153 }, 
    { x:4, y: 146 }, 
    { x:5, y: 163 }, 
    { x:6, y: 182 }, 
    { x:7, y: 178 }, 
    { x:8, y: 179 },
    { x:9, y: 181 },
    { x:10, y: 178 }
  ]
}]

nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
    .margin({left: 100})
    .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
    .transitionDuration(350)
    .showLegend(true)
    .showYAxis(true)
    .showXAxis(true);


  chart.xAxis.axisLabel('Month');
  chart.yAxis.axisLabel('Sales in Milions');

  d3.select('#chart svg').datum(data).call(chart);

  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

  return chart;
});
```

```css
#chart svg {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://nvd3.org/assets/js/nv.d3.js"></script>
<link href="http://nvd3.org//assets/css/nv.d3.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="chart">
    <svg> </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome... Is it possible to have re-sizable charts? so it occupy the whole space that its container let it to have?

Comment: Yes sure, you have just to add `nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);` in your code. I edited my answer to include this. Please consider upvoting my answer :)